# Sql Decode in BI-Publisher

Tags: sql, bi-publisher

I have this query:

```
select nm_strgp brand 
from co_strgp
where id_strgp_lv='2';
```

One value in this column is `HOLLAND &amp; BARRETT` but i want to display it as `HOLLAND & BARRETT` in BI publisher. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100) to unescape the special XMLcharacters.

```
SQL> select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT('HOLLAND &amp; BARRETT',1) from dual;

DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT('HOLLAND&AMP;BARRETT',1)
--------------------------------------------
HOLLAND & BARRETT
```